# AJAX GET request goes to localhost:0 on Chrome IOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, chrome-ios

I have a website that load JQuery that triggers a AJAX call to a API, this call works in all browsers except one, Chrome iOS. Using [Weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre-docs/latest/) I got that my requests is going to `http://localhost:0/chromecheckurl` and I don't have any idea how to fix it.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://www.example.com/api",
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  type: 'GET',
  async: true,
  cache: false
}).done( (data) ->
  # some code
)
```

There is a blog post on NewRelic that talk about it, but didn't said any solution - [NewRelic blog post](http://blog.newrelic.com/2014/04/11/crazy-things-found-developing-new-relic-browser/).

I really appreciate any help,

Thanks

Comment: according to the page you linked this is an chrome-ios bug... so not much we can do about it... you should report it to google.

Comment: both these bug reports appear to be related: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=347831 & https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=346504

Comment: are you by any chance using [xhook](https://github.com/jpillora/xhook)?

Comment: @NDM no, I'm not using xhook. I saw that there a issue there about it.